# Dynamically capture the date and time for each check box selected

Tags: html

I am a little new to web development and need some help. I have a webform that has checkboxes as a selection. For each checkbox selected the user should be able to enter a date, time and pickup location.

I already have these fields on the form. My question is how do I capture and report this information for every checkbox selected.

I anticipate some great responses as this site has been a very huge resource so far.

Comment: What backend language are you using? php? ruby? java? .NET? python? other? Also, what have you tried so far? This is an extremely common (if not, **the** most common) problem, which means there are thousands of tutorials a quick [Google search](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=html+send+data+to+server&oq=html+send+data+to+server0) away. Perhaps you're stuck at a particular point, in which case, can you post some code, and explain the exact point where you're stuck?

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle link to show where you are stuck? That way, it will be easier for others to answer

Comment: Thanks for the reply Christian Varga. Back end language is PHP. I will create a fiddle shortly.

Comment: Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ypkfo52q/. Basically when each checkbox is selected the user should be able to entire a date and time for each. I haven't started any coding as yet as I am seeking some guidelines as to how to the best method to get it done.

Comment: Implemented a different solution [Using hidden text boxes][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31092251/show-text-box-using-variable