# Show text box using variable

Tags: javascript

I have a need to use the value of a variable to show a text box. For the life of me I can't get it to work. I am no expert in java script so I am seeking your help. Below is the html and the java script:

```js
function valueChanged(me)

{
 var check_id = me.id + "dt"
 alert (check_id)
 
    if($('.tour_selected').is(":checked")) 
    $(check_id).val.show();
    else
        $(check_id).val.hide();
}
```

```html
<input class="t1dt" type="text" name="keywords_other_option" value="" id="t1dt" placeholder=" Select date+time for>" style="display: none">

<input class="tour_selected col-md-1" type="checkbox" name="ATV and Falls " value="ATV and Falls" id="t1" onchange=" return valueChanged(this)">ATV and Falls
<br>
```

As you can see the ID is been concatenated and displayed. However is not been passed into the IF function to unhide/hide the text box.

Thanks for your assistance

Comment: are you want to use jQuery library or JavaScript  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include jquery, to specify an id you need the pound sign, and you just do show/hide not val.show/hide.

```js
function valueChanged(me)

{
 var check_id = me.id + "dt"
 alert (check_id)
 
    if($('.tour_selected').is(":checked")) 
    $('#'+check_id).show();
    else
        $('#'+check_id).hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="t1dt" type="text" name="keywords_other_option" value="" id="t1dt" placeholder=" Select date+time for>" style="display: none">

<input class="tour_selected col-md-1" type="checkbox" name="ATV and Falls " value="ATV and Falls" id="t1" onchange=" return valueChanged(this)">ATV and Falls
<br>
```

Comment: This work perfectly, I will test it with multiple checkbox and text box and advise.

Comment: This works with multiple checkbox and textbox. Thank you depperm!

Answer (score 0):

I have used JavaScript for this and not jQuery library.

JS

```
function valueChanged() {

                var checkBoxElement = document.getElementById('tour_selected_id');
                var textBoxElement  =   document.getElementById('t1dt');

                console.log(checkBoxElement.style.visibility)
                if(checkBoxElement.checked) {
                    textBoxElement.style.display = 'block';
                }
                else{
                    textBoxElement.style.display = 'none';  
                }

            }
```

HTML

```
<input class="t1dt" id="t1dt" type="text" name="keywords_other_option" value="showhide" id="t1dt" placeholder=Select date+time for" style="display: none">

<input class="tour_selected col-md-1" id="tour_selected_id" type="checkbox" name="ATV and Falls " value="ATV and Falls" id="t1" 
onchange=" valueChanged()">ATV and Falls
<br>
```

Comment: Thanks RIYAJ KHAN. But the ID for the the box will change based on the checkbox checked: t1dt, t2dt, t3dt etc..

Comment: Could you please share the sample html for this?